# SSRS - combo chart?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am in the process of migrating an Excel report into SSRS, however the Excel report has a chart which I am struggling to replicate in SSRS - does anyone know if this is achievable and if so, how? I have everything set up (the blue and orange lines) but can't figure out how to add the dotted vertical lines which indicate what "category" the series falls in.

Mild 1.1
Moderate 2.2
Severe  3.3

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add striplines to almost achieve this. The problem is that thay actually sit on the axis and therefore behind the bars so you may have to adjust the bars to make it look better.

Here's an exmaple of adding a strip line to the striplines collection.

Click the X Axis and view the properties panel. Look for the striplines collection.

[image]

Now set the properties as you wish. In this example I used a database value to position the line but you can used fixed values where (e.g. 1.1). You can set he title for the line too. Look at the properties in bold.

[image]

When we run the report we get something like this

[image]

You can edit the stripline so it shades an area (by making it much wider) which in your case might look better as it would how the "bands" more clearly but that's just my opinion.